# SQL Practice: Multiple Order By

Tags: sql

I'm doing some practice questions with my teacher's given answers.

what I have so far:

```
select Sup.supplierID, SupplierName, sum(OD.Quantity) 
as ItemSupplied from Suppliers as Sup
inner join Products as P on Sup.SupplierID=P.SupplierID 
inner join OrderDetails as OD on
P.ProductID=OD.ProductID
group by Sup.supplierID order by ItemSupplied DESC, SupplierName ASC;
```

What my teacher's answer look like (The one with SupplierID):

[image]

My problem is I'm not having the same answer as the teacher's.
Which part I got wrong?

I got it by  changing sum() to COUNT(DISTINCT [ProductID from OrderDetails]) 
and ORDER BY this COUNT(DISTINCT [ProductID from OrderDetails]) in DESC first, then SupplierName in ASC:

```
select Sup.supplierID, SupplierName, count(DISTINCT OD.ProductID) 
as ItemSupplied from Suppliers as Sup
inner join Products as P on Sup.SupplierID=P.SupplierID 
inner join OrderDetails as OD on
P.ProductID=OD.ProductID
group by Sup.supplierID order by ItemSupplied DESC, SupplierName ASC;
```

Comment: What is your answer ? Please explain the exact mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your teacher is looking for a "count" of the products provided, as in the number of items in the catalog. Not a total quantity of items ordered. The specification isn't very clear.

```
 SELECT s.supplierid
      , s.suppliername
      , COUNT(p.productid)  AS cnt_items
   FROM Products p
   JOIN Suppliers s
     ON s.supplierid = p.supplierid  
  GROUP
     BY s.supplierid
      , s.suppliername
  ORDER
     BY COUNT(p.productid) DESC
      , s.suppliername ASC
```

---

If we want a count of items that have been ordered.. the number of products from a supplier that appear on at least one order...

```
 SELECT s.supplierid
      , s.suppliername
      , COUNT(DISTINCT o.productid) AS cnt_items
   FROM Products p
   JOIN Suppliers s
     ON s.supplierid = p.supplierid  
   JOIN OrderDetails o
     ON o.productid = p.productid
  GROUP
     BY s.supplierid
      , s.suppliername
  ORDER
     BY COUNT(DISTINCT o.productid) DESC
      , s.suppliername ASC
```

Comment: The COUNT(DISTINCT  OD.ProductID) and Order by it is the solution to my problem, so thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing SupplierName in your group by. The query should be failing.